# XSLT - Apply count and group by on multiple attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to get the amount of unique locations with type = city from this XML, but not sure how to do this..  I've been trying to apply counts, but this doesn't match up, I'll need to match a unique name aswell

```
<root>
    <report>
        <location name="Amsterdam" type="City">
            <amtPeople>1 Million+</amtPeople>
            <date>21-12-2017</date>
        </location>
        <location name="London" type="City">
            <amtPeople>1 Million+</amtPeople>
            <date>21-12-2017</date>
        </location>
        <location name="Boekelo" type="Village">
            <amtPeople>1 Million+</amtPeople>
            <date>21-12-2017</date>
        </location>
    </report>
    <report>
        <location name="Amsterdam" type="City">
            <amtPeople>1 Million+</amtPeople>
            <date>14-12-2017</date>
        </location>
        <location name="New York" type="City">
            <amtPeople>1 Million+</amtPeople>
            <date>14-12-2017</date>
        </location>
        <location name="Capelle" type="Village">
            <amtPeople>1 Million+</amtPeople>
            <date>14-12-2017</date>
        </location>
    </report>
</root>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="Log"/>
<xsl:variable name="AllCities" select="count($Log/root/report/location[@type='City'])"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <amtCities><xsl:value-of select="$AllCities"/></amtCities>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output based on the XML example:

```
<amtCities>3</amtCities>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the count on distinct-values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <amtcities>
          <xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(root/report/location[@type='City']/@name))"/>
      </amtcities>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn57

Answer (score 0):

1. why you using $log parameter is your XML store in this param?
2. As i notice that location/@type="City" are 4.
3. You can use `/root/report/location[@type='City']` only.

Comment: I use to assign param value manually its working fine:    

    <xsl:param name="Log" select="doc('File.xml')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="AllCities" select="count($Log/root/report/location[@type='City'])"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <amtCities><xsl:value-of select="$AllCities"/></amtCities>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: It's working, but I need all unique cities, so if Amsterdam appears twice or more, it only counts as one..

Answer (score 0):

**I use to assign param value manually its working fine:**

```
<xsl:param name="Log" select="doc('File.xml')"/>

<xsl:variable name="AllCities" select="count($Log/root/report/location[@type='City'])"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<amtCities><xsl:value-of select="$AllCities"/></amtCities>
</xsl:template>
```

I am using oxygen for transform and SAXON-PE-9.6.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:param name="Log" select="doc('File.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <amtcities>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values($Log/root/report/location[@type='City']/@name))"/>
        </amtcities>
    </xsl:template>
```